# How to adjust tool via mouse after first use?

Tags: modifiers, bevel, operator, tools, mouse

Say for Blender 3.x+ versions, while using edit mode tools such as scale, bevel, extrude, etc, a side operator menu shows that allows customization and extra control over the tool's behaviour. Now once I use that menu, say in Bevel I increase the segmentation over a cylinder, thereafter I lose mouse-control over the tool's axis. Now using the axis via the mouse will lead to another instance of Bevel instead of continuing to adjust the current operation, the operator menu works fine of course.. Is there anything to allow readjust via mouse?

Comment: No, because adjusting via mouse only works before confirming the action. The operator menu on the bottom left does not show up before confirming, so it is only to readjust what you did before, maybe if you did not get it right with the mouse or want to finetune a setting you got via mouse. It is not supposed to switch between mouse and menu adjustment. If you for example scale on X accidentally and left-click to confirm, this was the operation. Without the side menu there would be no chance to switch to Y if this was the axis you intended to scale on, you would have to undo with Ctrl+Z.

Comment: It is a bit like pressing a key for the axis to move or scale or rotate etc. or entering values for the exact distance, angle whatever... as long as you do not confirm the action, you can change these things - but after confirmation you lose this ability, it's either undo or hope there is an operator menu to help correcting it.